# php mvc localization problems with router

Tags: php, model-view-controller, routes, localization, router

So I've started to study php MVC and I finished several works with helping that. But now I have a problem with localization of project. Until now I have not worked with multi language sites. I have a problem with router. Can you help to configure my router for multi language site?

```
    <?php

class Router
{

    private $routes;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $routesPath = ROOT . '/config/routes.php';
        $this->routes = include($routesPath);
    }

    /**
     * Returns request string
     */
    private function getURI()
    {
        if (!empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
            return trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');
        }
    }

    public function run()
    {
        // Получить строку запроса
        $uri = $this->getURI();

        // Проверить наличие такого запроса в routes.php
        foreach ($this->routes as $uriPattern => $path) {

            // Сравниваем $uriPattern и $uri
            if (preg_match("~$uriPattern~", $uri)) {

                // Получаем внутренний путь из внешнего согласно правилу.
                $internalRoute = preg_replace("~$uriPattern~", $path, $uri);

                // Определить контроллер, action, параметры

                $segments = explode('/', $internalRoute);

                $controllerName = array_shift($segments) . 'Controller';
                $controllerName = ucfirst($controllerName);

                $actionName = 'action' . ucfirst(array_shift($segments));

                $parameters = $segments;

                // Подключить файл класса-контроллера
                $controllerFile = ROOT . '/controllers/' .
                        $controllerName . '.php';

                if (file_exists($controllerFile)) {
                    include_once($controllerFile);
                }

                // Создать объект, вызвать метод (т.е. action)
                $controllerObject = new $controllerName;


                $result = call_user_func_array(array($controllerObject, $actionName), $parameters);


                if ($result != null) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here is my url routes

```
<?php

return array(
    'service/([0-9]+)' => 'service/view/$1',
    'product/([0-9]+)' => 'product/view/$1', // actionView в ProductController
    'contacts' => 'contacts/index',
    'about' => 'about/index',
    'gallery' => 'gallery/index',
    'gallery/page-([0-9]+)' => 'gallery/index/$1',
    'alboum/([0-9]+)' => 'gallery/alboum/$1',

    // Управление товарами:    
    'admin/product/create' => 'adminProduct/create',
    'admin/product/update/([0-9]+)' => 'adminProduct/update/$1',
    'admin/product/delete/([0-9]+)' => 'adminProduct/delete/$1',
    'admin/product' => 'adminProduct/index',

    'admin/clear/([0-9]+)' => 'adminProduct/clear/$1',
    'admin/productSlider' => 'adminProduct/index',




     // Управление сервисами:    
    'admin/service/create' => 'adminService/create',
    'admin/service/update/([0-9]+)' => 'adminService/update/$1',
    'admin/service/delete/([0-9]+)' => 'adminService/delete/$1',
    'admin/service' => 'adminService/index',

    'admin/remove/([0-9]+)' => 'adminService/remove/$1',
    'admin/serviceSlider' => 'adminService/index',

    // Управление контактами: 
    'adminContacts/update/([0-9]+)' => 'adminContacts/update/$1',
    'adminContacts' => 'adminContacts/index',


    // Управление О нас:    
    'adminAbout/update/([0-9]+)' => 'adminAbout/update/$1',
    'adminAbout' => 'adminAbout/index',
    // Управление Review:
    'adminReview/delete/([0-9]+)' => 'adminReview/delete/$1',
    'adminReview/create' => 'adminReview/create',
    'adminReview' => 'adminReview/index',

    // Управление Gallery:
    'adminGallery/delete/([0-9]+)' => 'adminGallery/delete/$1',
    'adminGallery' => 'adminGallery/index',
    // Управление Alboum:
    'adminAlboum/delete/([0-9]+)' => 'adminAlboum/delete/$1',
    'adminAlboum' => 'adminAlboum/index',

    // Админпанель:
    'admin/delete/([0-9]+)' => 'admin/delete/$1',
    'admin' => 'admin/index',

    'login' => 'adminLogin',




    '' => 'site/index', // actionIndex в SiteController

);
```

Comment: Any suggestions?